# Open dialog after closing another - populate dropdown with ajax call - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show a `dialog` with `jquery` after another `dialog` is closed.
Here is the first dialog
[image]

When I press the `Close` button another `dialog` needs to be showed. This dialog which has a `drop down`, and I need to populate this `dropdown` with `ajax` call.

[image]

The problem is that I keep get this error on console: `TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined`. and the method from the controller is never reached.

This is the code that I'm using:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#saveGeometryType_dialog").draggable({ handle: ".modal-header" });

    function saveElements(options) {
    }

    function closeDialog(options) {
        var $temp = $("<input/>", { id: 'temp' });
        //$temp.val($(options.element).text()).select();
        //document.execCommand("copy");

        //var title = $("#geometry-dialog").dialog("option", "title");
        //console.log($temp);
        $temp.remove();
        var title = "Linestring";

        $('#saveGeometryType_dialog').modal('show');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PlotDescriptions/GetCodes/" + title,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#ddlCode").get(0).options.length = 0;
                $("#ddlCode").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select code", "-1"); 
 
                $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                    $("#ddlCode").get(0).options[$("#ddlCode").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#ddlCode").get(0).options.length = 0;
                alert("Failed to load names");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="saveGeometryType_dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Save geometry</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p></p>
                <div class="saveGeometryType-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"> Cod </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> <select id="ddlCod">
                        </select> </div>
                    </div>
                       
                </div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button onclick="saveElements({ 'element': '#saveGeometryType_dialog .modal-body > p', 'target': 'saveGeometryType_dialog .modal-body' });$('#saveGeometryType_dialog').modal('hide');" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button onclick="closeDialog({ 'element': '#saveGeometryType_dialog .modal-body > p', 'target': 'saveGeometryType_dialog .modal-body' });$('#saveGeometryType_dialog').modal('hide');" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This is the controller method that I need to reach. The parameter from the method should be the title from the first dialog, in this case the Linestring.:

```
  [WebMethod]public static ArrayList GetCodes(string geometryType)
    {
        return new ArrayList()
        {
            new { Value = 1, Display = "Code1" },
            new { Value = 2, Display = "Code2" }
        };
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typo?    <div class="col-md-4"> <select id="ddlCod**e**">

Comment: Yes, indeed was a typo., now always appears the alert("Failed to load names"), it does not enter on the controller method.